# Parse multiple servers for the latest modifed file within a subdirectory with a specific text within it

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, findstr

I have multiple servers having a specific folder name within which there are multiple subdirectories. I would like to look into the latest file within that subdirectory (each subdirectory will have a latest timestamped log file). I would like to parse the content of the latest file found in each of the subdirectory and look for a keyword i specify and if found output to an excel file or text file that particular line with the foldername/subdirectoryname/the line matching the condition.

Eg:
Server1

- Log folder 1

  - Text File 1 (latest Time stamp)
  - Text File 2 (yesterday timestamp)
  - Text File 3 (Day before yesterday Time Stamp)...so on..
- Log Folder 2

  - Text File 1 (latest Time stamp)
  - Text File 2 (yesterday timestamp)
  - Text File 3 (Day before yesterday Time Stamp)...so on..

I am looking for a keyword of failed or success within the text file of each folder with latest Time stamp, and if failed or log missing, then output to a text file or CSV file.

Have tried using Findstr and Dir with date attributes, Not able to achieve the results i am looking for.  I am still experimenting with various suggestions on the internet,  nothing gets me to what i am planning to achieve yet.  Either it can be done with Powershell or Windows batch command,  Running out of ideas and my deadline is closing and hence getting desperate to seek help. The other way i have is to manually open each folder sort by date open each file and record it manually.  I have just around 800 such folders to manually go through.  Though i have already started that exercise of doing it manually.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the fastest solution is to use something like ripgrep >>> BurntSushi/ripgrep: ripgrep recursively searches directories for a regex pattern while respecting your gitignore — https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep <<<

Comment: if adding a utility aint do-able, then write a function to get the newest file from a target dir, another to parse that file, and wrap it in code to feed paths into the 1st, the file into the 2nd, and output the results per dir into a CSV file.  do it one step at a time and things are fairly easy ... there is lots of code for the 1st two found in almost any net search. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Hi the code below should fit your needs as basis, adopt to your own needs.
Used my userprofile temp for the search.

```
$searchRoot = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\Users\Valgrind\AppData\Local\Temp" -ErrorAction Ignore
foreach ($item in $searchRoot)
{
    $subcontent = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $item.Fullname -Recurse  -ErrorAction Ignore
    
    if ($subcontent.Count -ne 0)
    {
        $latestfile = $subcontent | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
        $raw = Get-Content -Path $latestfile -Raw

        if ($raw -like "*success*")
        {
            Write-Output "Success in file: $latestfile"
            Add-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\success.log" -Value $latestfile
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "Success not in file: $latestfile"
        }
    }
}
```